# Display related drop-downs using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, css

I have 3 drop-down boxes containing values of age, sport and relationship and all elements of them are loaded when we open the webpage.

Age = [0-10, 10-20, 20-30, 30-40]

Sport = [Soccer, Tennis, Golf, Chess]

Relationship = [Son, Brother, Father, Friend]

Now, elements of all three are inter-related with a mapping. For example, someone in age 20-30 can be a son, brother OR a friend; and can play soccer, tennis OR chess.

I want these drop downs to be dynamic, i.e, on selecting any value of any drop-down, the related options are displayed in the other two drop-downs. Shouldn't be an ajax call I think, since the all the fields are already loaded on the client.

Can anyone please tell me how can this be done in HTML using javascript(or any other way)? Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: what you have tried.? show your code.

Comment: Right now, I just have a form for 3 drop-downs of these fields, all static. I have minimal knowledge of javascript and couldn't find anything when I looked up. So I thought if anybody who has done it before might help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

U need to push the java script in this code. Which format you use. I will send the answer in your question with code